# Ion.context uses same object for every request

Tags: android, android-ion

I was just going through the source code of [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) and found that Ion uses static HashMap `static HashMap<String, Ion> instances = new HashMap<String, Ion>();` for storing Ion objects and calling `Ion.with(context)` should return the same instance as evident from the code (correct me if I am wrong)

```
 public static Ion getDefault(Context context) {
        return getInstance(context, "ion");
    }

public static Ion getInstance(Context context, String name) {
    if (context == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("Can not pass null context in to retrieve ion instance");
    Ion instance = instances.get(name);
    if (instance == null)
        instances.put(name, instance = new Ion(context, name));
    return instance;
}
```

but when I compare objects it returns false. Can anyone tell me what am I missing ?

```
Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf( Ion.with(getApplicationContext()).equals(Ion.with(getApplicationContext())) ));
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I was missing this line

```
  public static LoadBuilder<Builders.Any.B> with(Context context) {
        return getDefault(context).build(context);
    }

 public LoadBuilder<Builders.Any.B> build(Context context) {
        return new IonRequestBuilder(ContextReference.fromContext(context), this);
    }
```

It uses same Ion object but returns new builder every time.